# TailwindCSS: Can't use breakpoints for box-shadow

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying TailwindCSS for the first time, and it seems I can't use breakpoints for box-shadows. All the others breakpoints are working fine except for the box-shadow.

Btw, I'm using a custom box-shadow.

HTML:

```
<div 
   class="w-auto h-screen pl-10 mt-20 pt-12 absolute left-0 top-0 bg-gray-900 shadow-menu md:shadow-none"
>
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      base: ["Quicksand", "sans-serif"],
      title: ["Belgrano", "serif"]
    },
    extend: {},
    boxShadow: {
      menu: "0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
    }
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable `Pseudo-Class Variants` for `boxShadow` in your `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```js
boxShadow: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus']
```

This will allow you to tweak `boxShadow` based on responsive classes, hover or focus.

Your `tailwind.config.js` will look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      base: ["Quicksand", "sans-serif"],
      title: ["Belgrano", "serif"]
    },
    extend: {},
    boxShadow: {
      menu: "0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
    }
  },
  variants: {
    boxShadow: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus']
  },
  plugins: []
};
```

I hope this helps.

Resources https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#app